# Setup master-master replication using mariabackup

Tags: mariadb, mysql-replication

Can please advise how I do master master replication?
How can I get the exact position while the production server is keep on running and busy?
To SCP to another server took about 7,8h , after waiting and waiting I dont see it replication or syncing correctly. I guess it couldnt catch up with the master A gtid.
Can please share with me the steps?

Comment: How many GB of data?  What parameters did you use for replication, such as multiple-threads?  Show us the backup command.  SCP may not be necessary.

Comment: roughly 60GB to 160GB. im using mariabackup. mariadb version 10.2

Answer (score 0):

With the software already set up on the Slave, but without Replication set up, this may be the most efficient way:

```
mariabackup --host the-master ... | mysql --host the-slave-to-be ...
```

Note that there is no SCP, and the dump never touches the disk.  This one-line script can be run on either server or even a third server.